# Can't run vi from terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, vi

Every time I execute these commands:

```
vi
```

or

```
vim
```

in the terminal, it gives me the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/vi: No such file or directory
```

or

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/vim: No such file or directory
```

How do I get it to look at `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`?

```
type -a vi vim
```

returns

```
vi is /usr/bin/vi
vim is /usr/bin/vim
```

and

```
echo $PATH
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/Users/carlo/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/carlo/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

I effed up my settings when I was screwing around with MacVim and Homebrew. And now I can't even start vim with vi or vim.

Comment: What does this command return: `type -a vi vim` ? What about `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: @glennjackman I added the output of these two commands in the question.

Comment: What about these: `ls -l /usr/bin/{vi,vim}; hash -t vi vim`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks. bmike's answer below fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your path to be the following and then you should have temporary control (or just unset the $PATH and type things in exactly like /usr/bin/vi whatever)

```
 export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Once you've confirmed all is well, you'll want to sort out the scripts that run each time you log in and set $PATH or just be sure that you delete things from /usr/local to clean up the problems.

Comment: THANK YOU! That works. Do these settings go in a specific file that I can take a look at? For example, when I execute the command above, what file changes that makes the settings change?

Comment: Why not spin that second question off on how to determine which startup files are being run. My guess is you'll need to list the OS version, homebrew version and perhaps look into what exact shell you use if you are not using bash (the default shell).

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: A;sp note if you have /opt/local/bin you have also been playingwith Macports and only one of Macports or Homebrew should be used or you get issues similar to this

Comment: Might want to look at your ~/.bash_profile to check for any settings that might conflict.